# Update UI item from another class and thread

Tags: c#, multithreading, winforms, irc

I've seen other similar questions here but I can't seem to find a solution for my specific problem.

I'm writing a Twitch Bot and need to update a listbox on the main form when a message is received from the server. I made a custom event in my TwitchBot.cs class called `OnReceive` that looks like this:

```
public delegate void Receive(string message);
public event Receive OnReceive;

private void TwitchBot_OnReceive(string message)
{
    string[] messageParts = message.Split(' ');
    if (messageParts[0] == "PING")
    {
        // writer is a StreamWriter object
        writer.WriteLine("PONG {0}", messageParts[1]);
    }
}
```

The event is raised in the `Listen()` method of my `TwitchBot` class:

```
private void Listen()
{
    //IRCConnection is a TcpClient object
    while (IRCConnection.Connected)
    {
        // reader is a StreamReader object.
        string message = reader.ReadLine();

        if (OnReceive != null)
        {
            OnReceive(message);
        }
    }
}
```

When connecting to the IRC back-end, I call the `Listen()` method from a new thread:

```
Thread thread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(Listen));
thread.Start();
```

I then subscribed to the `OnReceive` event in the main form using the following line:

```
// bot is an instance of my TwitchBot class
bot.OnReceive += new TwitchBot.Receive(UpdateChat);
```

Finally, `UpdateChat()` is a method in the main form used to update a listbox on it:

```
private void UpdateChat(string message)
{
    lstChat.Items.Insert(lstChat.Items.Count, message);
    lstChat.SelectedIndex = lstChat.Items.Count - 1;
    lstChat.Refresh();
}
```

When I connect to the server and the `Listen()` method runs, I get an `InvalidOperationException` that says "Additional information: Cross-thread operation not valid: Control 'lstChat' accessed from a thread other than the thread it was created on."

I've looked up how to update UI from a different thread but can only find things for WPF and I'm using winforms.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Cross-thread operation not valid: Control accessed from a thread other than the thread it was created on](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/142003/cross-thread-operation-not-valid-control-accessed-from-a-thread-other-than-the)

Comment: I've looked at that link and still don't have a solution for this. Could you please explain what I'm looking for in that link/how it relates to my problem? I don't understand how to specifically use the [System.Windows.Forms.Control.Invoke](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Windows.Forms.Control.Invoke.aspx) it references in that link with the code I posted in the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should check the [`Invoke for UI thread`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19023209/1225337)

```
private void UpdateChat(string message)
{
    if(this.InvokeRequired)
    {
        this.Invoke(new MethodInvoker(delegate {
            lstChat.Items.Insert(lstChat.Items.Count, message);
            lstChat.SelectedIndex = lstChat.Items.Count - 1;
            lstCat.Refresh();
        }));           
    } else {
            lstChat.Items.Insert(lstChat.Items.Count, message);
            lstChat.SelectedIndex = lstChat.Items.Count - 1;
            lstCat.Refresh();
    }
}
```

Comment: Awesome! This is exactly what I needed. Thanks for linking that informative write-up and for showing me how to use invoke. This works great now!